# How to publish opencv Mat image in ROS Fuerte

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I went through the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages) about conversion between ROS and OpenCV images.... To publish opencv image, it has to be converted to ROS image msg.

Now what I have is just a Mat image,

```
Mat opencv_img ;
```

I tried :

```
cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;

cv_ptr->image = opencv_img.clone();


ros::Publisher pub;
 
pub.publish(cv_ptr->toImgMsg());
```

I get an error :-

```
 T* boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator->() const [with T = cv_bridge::CvImage]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61462/how-to-publish-opencv-mat-image-in-ros-fuerte/) by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Similar error is reported and solved](http://answers.ros.org/question/11430/sending-the-image-using-cvbridge/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-24**:
I followed as said in the answer.... cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new CvImage() ); Then , opencv_img.copyTo(cv_ptr->image);

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-24**:
But even then I get error :-  **error: expected type-specifier before ‘CvImage’**
error:  **expected ‘)’ before ‘CvImage’**

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-24**:
usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp: In constructor ‘boost::shared_ptr::shared_ptr(Y*) [with Y = int, T = cv_bridge::CvImage]’:
/home/karthik/Desktop/pcl/sandbox/Image_processing/src/example.cpp:116:47:   instantiated from here

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-24**:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:187:50: error: cannot convert int * to cv_bridge::CvImage * in initialization

**Comment by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on 2013-04-30**:
Maybe you should use the constructor of cv_bridge::CvImage to create a new instance of this class instead of using its pointer (CvImagePtr), but pay attention to fill all the necessary headers rightly before publishing.

**Comment by [KarthikMurugan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4447/karthikmurugan/) on 2013-04-30**:
How to fill the headers ?? There are members such as seq ,time, frame id... what should I put into these ??

**Comment by [Mike Gao](https://answers.ros.org/users/1629/mike-gao/) on 2013-05-03**:
cv_bridge::CvImage cv_img;
cv_img.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
cv_img.header.frame_id = "your_camera_frame";
cv_img.encoding = "mono8"; (or "bgr8")
cv_img.image = img_topub;
img_pub_.publish(cv_img.toImageMsg());